# pandas string selection to include and exclude

Tags: string, pandas

I trying to include the text contains words like "AV" but to exclude any word that contains like "AV-DEFAULT"

Below code, is not getting what i want. It turn out the data with "AV-DEFAULT" are selected.

```
df = df[df.STRUCTURALSTATUS.str.contains('AV', regex=False, case=False, na=False) & ~ 
(df['STRUCTURALSTATUS'] != 'AV-DEFAULT')]
```

Comment: Please provide some examples of strings and expected output. That'll help us to solve your problem in the best possible way,

Comment: @ManishSaraswat  Hi for example , strings like AV, AV IE, AV (11), AV-EE, AG AV will be selected but strings like AV-DEFAULT, O - AV-DEFAULT, C - AV-DEFAULT will be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern visible in the selected string is they always start or ends with `AV`. 
You can use `.startswith` / `.endswith` string function to check the existence of a word.

```
# sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['AV', 'AV IE', 'AV (11)', 'AV-EE', 'AG AV','O - AV-DEFAULT']})

# create a new column 
df['new_name'] = df['names'].loc[(df.names.str.startswith('AV') | df.names.str.endswith('AV'))]

# output
    names           new_name
0   AV                 AV
1   AV IE              AV IE
2   AV (11)                AV (11)
3   AV-EE              AV-EE
4   AG AV              AG AV
5   O - AV-DEFAULT     NaN
6   HEAVY DAMAGE       NaN
```

**Update 1:**

```
df['new_name'] = df.names[df.names.str.contains(r'(?!AV-DEFAULT)AV(?!\w)')]
```

**Regex Explanation:** 
1. `(?!..)` This says don't match the string which AV-DEFAULT 
2. `AV` Here we match strings which has AV 
3. `(?!\w)` Don't match AV is it is followed by any letter, like in (HEAVY DAMAGE)

**Update 2:** This take remove strings which starts with AV such as AVAILABLE.

```
df.names[df.names.str.contains(r'((?!AV-DEFAULT)AV(?!\w))|^AV')]
```

**Update 3:** How to run the code.

```
# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['AV', 'AV IE', 'AV (11)', 'AV-EE', 'AG AV','O - AV-DEFAULT','HEAVY DAMAGE','AVAILABLE(AFP)','AV-DEFAULT']}) 

# get new column
df['new_name'] = df.names[df.names.str.contains(r'((?!AV-DEFAULT)AV(?!\w))|^AVA')]

print(df)

    names           new_name
0   AV              AV
1   AV IE           AV IE
2   AV (11)         AV (11)
3   AV-EE           AV-EE
4   AG AV           AG AV
5   O - AV-DEFAULT  NaN
6   HEAVY DAMAGE    NaN
7   AVAILABLE(AFP)  AVAILABLE(AFP)
8   AV-DEFAULT      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are many AV or AV-DEFAULT like strings combination not limited to those. Hence i thought should be using like str.contains function to find....

Comment: Did you try with all other combinations ? Where does it fail ?

Comment: Hi what i trying to mean is the code work but when there are new "AV" like combination i have to add into the code again and again....

Comment: Like what ? Give examples.

Comment: Hi, e.g
  AVAILABLE,
  AV-DEFAULT,
O - AV,
SCRAP AV,
AV (SMELL),
AV (NON FD GRADE - FB ROUGH),
AV (NON FD GRADE - FB STAINED),
O - AV-DEFAULT,
IEW AV,
AGENT AV,
C - AV-DEFAULT,
HEAVY DAMAGE (this to exclude),
AV - HOLD,
AVAILABLE (AFP),
AV ( RC ),

Comment: I've updated the answer. So, based on these examples, the answer comes down to finding if a string starts / ends with AV.

Comment: Hi, the str.startswith and str.endswith able to achieve what I want for all the words start with AV and ends with AV. But I want to specify to exclude just this word "AV-Default". How can i modify the code to exclude that word? Thanks!

Comment: or can i just drop the row that contain the word "AV-DEFAULT"

Comment: If dropping is easier for you, you can do that. However, I've added an update to the answer, please check.

Comment: thanks, but the word like "AVAILABLE" and AVAILABLE (xxx) need to be included too. In this case, word like "AVAILABLE xxxx" excluded. How can i modify the code to include them in.

Comment: Is AVAILABLE always going to be at the start of the string?

Comment: Yes...at the start of the string

Comment: i got this warning : C:\Users\okl\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.

Comment: pls see my first post question with add-in picture of the output

Comment: That's a warning, you can ignore it. And, I get the result as you require. Please check the updated answer,

Comment: hi , "O - AV-DEFAULT" is excluded but the word "AV-DEFAULT" still show , should be excluded too.

Comment: Thanks it got what i want !!